# How can I use CSS on form.ImageFiled in Django?

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4

I would like to apply CSS to form.ImageFiled in Django same as Charfeild but
I got the error.

```
  File "/Users/hogehoge/Desktop/hoge/hoge/forms.py", line 42, in PostForm
    photo = forms.ImageField(label='Image', validators=[file_size],widget=forms.ImageField(attrs={'class': 'fileinput'}))
  File "/Users/hoge/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 545, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'
```

How can I apply CSS CSS on form.ImageFiled?

forms.py

```
photo = forms.ImageField(label='Image', validators=[file_size],widget=forms.ImageField(attrs={'class': 'fileinput'}))
```

html

```
<div class="col-8 col-lg-4">{{ form.photo }}</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using the ImageField as a Widget class instead of a FileInput or ClearableFileInput.

Perhaps this will work:

```
photo = forms.ImageField(label='Image', validators=[file_size],widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'fileinput'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
    .
    .
    .
        <div>
          <label for="id_photo" class="filelabel">ファイルを添付</label>
          <div class="col-8 col-lg-4">{{ form.photo|add_class:"fileinput" }} 
          </div>
        </div>
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
.
.
.

    'widget_tweaks',
]
```

I succeeded this code.